# Las pruebas pasan cuando las ejecuto por separado, pero fallan cuando las ejecuto juntas

Tags: mongodb, ruby, rspec

El proyecto usa MongoDB, por lo tanto estas respuestas no me fueron de ayuda:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46860735/rspec-tests-pass-in-isolation-but-fail-when-run-together), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037237/rspec-tests-fail-with-factorygirl-pass-when-isolated?noredirect=1&lq=1), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376595/rspec-test-passes-in-isolation-but-fails-when-run-with-other-tests)

Puedo ejecutar cualquier archivo, o grupo de archivos, de pruebas en Rspec que pasarán satisfactoriamente. Pero cuando ejecuto todas las pruebas `rspec spec/*` fallan bastantes.

```
Finished in 23 minutes 45 seconds (files took 23.02 seconds to load)
2071 examples, 1357 failures, 28 pending
```

El proyecto es un poco viejo. Utiliza la version 3.6 de MongoDB, Ruby 2.5.1 con el Framework de [Padrino](http://padrinorb.com/). En las pruebas utilizamos DatabaseCleaner y [Fabrication](https://github.com/paulelliott/fabrication). Muchos errores dicen el clasico mensaje de `Sinatra doesn’t know this ditty.`

```
61) BlogController POST :create Microsite request should return code 12 for invalid token
      Failure/Error: @response_body = JSON.parse(last_response.body)

      JSON::ParserError:
        784: unexpected token at '<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
          <style type="text/css">
          body { text-align:center;font-family:helvetica,arial;font-size:22px;
            color:#888;margin:20px}
          #c {margin:0 auto;width:500px;text-align:left}
          </style>
        </head>
        <body>
          <h2>Sinatra doesn’t know this ditty.</h2>
          <img src='http://localhost.la/__sinatra__/404.png'>
          <div id="c">
            Try this:
            <pre># in app.rb
        class Microsite
          post &#x27;&#x2F;v1&#x2F;microsite&#x2F;blog&#x27; do
            &quot;Hello World&quot;
          end
        end
        </pre>
          </div>
        </body>
        </html>
        '
```

Adicionalmente, mi jefe utiliza MAC y tuvo un problema similar relacionado con WiredTiger, pero yo uso Ubuntu y revisando los logs de MongoDB no encuentro error alguno con WiredTiger al ejecutar las pruebas.

Mi jefe lo arreglo con una configuración del sistema. Aparentemente Rspec intentaba abrir todos los archivos para ejecutar las pruebas y se quedaba sin memoria el proceso o algo por el estilo
¿Tendré qué hacer algo similar?

[config.ru](https://pastebin.com/LzeAxMUn)

[spec/spec_helper.rb](https://pastebin.com/RQ0Za3VR)

Comment: Años que no trabajo con Sinatra, pero supongo no está demás preguntar lo obvio, ¿tienes definido ese `post '/v1/microsite/blog'` endpoint que reclama no se encuentra?. Dudo que tenga que ver en algo MongoDB, porque el error te lo tira a nivel de enrutador, ni siquiera ha alcanzado a llegar al controlador. Agrega a tu pregunta algo de código, como `config.ru`, `spec/spec_helper.rb`, quizás `config/environment.rb`, se me imagina que pueda ser algo de configuración de la app, igual agregar alguno de los tests y su contraparte en la carpeta de `app/` no haría daño.

Comment: @AlterLagos Si claro, como mencionaba, al ejecutar ese archivo por separado sale satisfactorio. El problema pasa cuando ejecuto todas las pruebas.

Por cierto, ya agregue los archivos que mencionabas, el unico que no tengo es el `config/environment.rb`

Comment: El código debe estar en la pregunta y no en un enlace hacia otro servicio. Por favor leer [mcve] y [ask]. Saludos